# cant open or install open java runtime

Tags: java

I'd like to install java runtime but it just does Reading package lists...

```
Error!
E: Encountered a section with no Package: header
E: Problem with MergeList /var/lib/apt/lists/repo.steampowered.com_steam_dists_precise_steam_i18n_Translation-en
E: The package lists or status file could not be parsed or opened.
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your control file is corrupted.

Try this:

```
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists
sudo mkdir -p /var/lib/apt/lists/partial
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Comment: didnt work just did W: GPG error: http://deb.opera.com stable InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 63F7D4AFF6D61D45
E: Encountered a section with no Package: header
E: Problem with MergeList /var/lib/apt/lists/repo.steampowered.com_steam_dists_precise_steam_i18n_Translation-en
E: The package lists or status file could not be parsed or opened.

Comment: then i did it twice and it said error unbable to locate archive use --fix-missing?

Comment: fianlly third try and it worked thx bacon!

Comment: Please consider marking the answer as "accepted" by clicking on the button bellow the downvote arrow, if the anwer satisfied your expectations :)